# Compiling Python3.6 gives fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory

Tags: makefile, python-3.6, zlib

I want to compile python3 from source so I followed the instructions. 
However, during the `make` command I get the error

`./Modules/zlibmodule.c:10:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory`

How do I solve this without having to install zlib as I do not have root access. Is there a way to skip this file while compilation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use python-dev instead, it includes header files, a static library and development tools for building Python modules, extending the Python interpreter or embedding Python in applications. To install this package, enter:

For Python version 3.x+
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev

Comment: I dont have root access :|